# Locked down user

Tags: permissions

I am a retired Windows IT person who is just starting with Ubuntu and it is GREAT.  So I apologize for a dumb question.

How do I make a user who can ONLY see one directory (or just his own directories)?

If I add a new user like “billy” the he can see and change his own stuff, but he can also see and copy almost everything on the computer.

I do not want “billy” to even be able to SEE anything except his own directory.

I tried it as “billy” being a “Custom” user and then as a “Desktop” user.   He can use PCManFM and see everything for every user including the Root files.

I want a “Locked Down” user

Comment: The problem with approaching it that way is that permissions are done by directory. So directory Foo may have permission for non-owners (like Billy) to be able to see it. You are asking for a whole big permission overlay on top of the existing permission scheme...and there are several already (Access Control Lists, AppArmor, SELinux, Containers). None are simple.

Comment: Is this a Desktop Environment for Billy? Or is he ssh-ing into a server environment? FTP, for example, can be configured to jail logins to a specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a user from the `sudo` group.  This will keep the user from being able to access restricted directories (directories to which the user and the user's groups have no permissions) and other user's `home` directories.

When deleting users from the `sudo` group be sure NOT to delete the real (or at least one full) administrator account from the system.

The command to delete a user from a group (sudo group in this case) is `sudo deluser <username> sudo`

You can confirm deletion of the user from the sudo group by running:
`sudo -l -U <username>`

You can view a list of all groups and the members of the group by listing the contents of the `/etc/group` file with this command - `cat /etc/group`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use LXD Containers**

Give Billy an account inside a Container instead of your main system. Billy cannot see out of the container, but you (the admin) can see in.

An LXD Container behaves rather like a Virtual Machine, but with much lower resource overhead. Billy cannot tell he's in a container unless he knows what he is looking for. He will see the container's /dev, /etc, /var, /usr, etc....

LXD Containers are super-easy to setup and maintain. It's one snap, ine image download, and about 10 minutes of setup. Maintenance is very much like maintaining any other install of Ubunru.

Several excellent tutorials on installing LXD and launching your first container are just a search engine away. Look for newer tutorials - 2018 and later.